# Sum the content of two divs in another div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

How can I sum  content in one div and content in another div .
I  tried this.

Sum of the checked checkboxes in one div

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".marca").click(
    function () {
        var ntot = 0;
        $(".marca:checked").each(function () {
            ntot += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#totalcreditos").val(ntot);
    })
    .change();
});


</script>
```

Another sum of the checkboxes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".marca1").click(
    function () {
        var ntot = 0;
        $(".marca1:checked").each(function () {
            ntot += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#totalcreditos1").val(ntot);
    })
    .change();
});
```

Here's where i tried to sum the two before divs putting all the checkboxes inside a span tag.

```
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".marca2").click(
    function () {
        var ntot = 0;
        $(".marca2:checked").each(function () {
            ntot += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#totalcreditos2").val(ntot);
    })
    .change();
});


</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="marca2"><input class="marca" type="checkbox" name="carga[0]"   
id="checkbox1" value="5.62"></span>
<span class="marca2"><input class="marca" type="checkbox" name="carga[1]"  
id="checkbox2" value="6.62"></span>


<p>Total Creditos:
<input type="text" id="totalcreditos" value="" />
</p>


<span class="marca2"><input class="marca1" type="checkbox" name="carga[2]"  
id="checkbox3" value="5.62"></span>
<span class="marca2"><input class="marca1" type="checkbox" name="carga[3]"  
id="checkbox4" value="6.62"></span>


<p>Total Creditos:
<input type="text" id="totalcreditos1" value="" />
</p>


<p>Total Creditos:
<input type="text" id="totalcreditos2" value="" />
</p>
```

Any help will be very helpful

Thanks.

Comment: please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Are you absolutely tied to that HTML structure? You're using lots of `id`s and `class`-es to identify elements, instead of creating a regular structure for the element to occupy to imply/create the relationships (that would make selection a lot, *lot* more simple).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ntot = $('.marca2 input:checked').get()
    .map(function(el) { return parseFloat($(el).val()); })
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)
;
$('#totalcreditos2').val(ntot);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for checked elements *with* class `marca2`, you want checked elements *inside* `marca2` wrappers:

```
 $(".marca2 input:checked").each(function () {
   ntot += parseFloat($(this).val());
 });
```